# DropdownList Selected Value as Parameter for another DropdownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I'm having a bit of a difficulty trying to accomplish my Goal here,

I have two dropdowns, I'd like to be able to change the values available within Dropdown_Objective according to the selected value within Dropdown_Parent. These dropdowns are contained within a TemplateField,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="20" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="VisitObjectiveKey" 
    onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ParentId" SortExpression="ParentId">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="UpdParentId" runat="server" Width="100%" SkinID="-1" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSource="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="ParentKeyDesc" DataValueField="ParentKey" >
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="ItemParentId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ParentId") %>' ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="InsParentId" runat="server" Width="100%" SkinID="-1" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSource="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="ParentKeyDesc" DataValueField="ParentKey" >
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Objective" SortExpression="Objective">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="UpdObjective" runat="server" Width="100%" SkinID="-1" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSource="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="ObjectiveKeyDesc" DataValueField="ObjectiveKey" >
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="ItemObjective" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Objective") %>' ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="InsObjective" runat="server" Width="100%" SkinID="-1" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSource="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="ObjectiveKeyDesc" DataValueField="ObjectiveKey" >
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

This is the SqlDatesource I'm trying to use for the Dropdown_Objective,

```
<asp:SqlDataSource  ID="SqlDataSource2" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="Select  ObjectiveKey, ObjectiveKeyDesc From T_Table Where ObjectiveKey = @ParentId">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UpdParentId" 
                                              Name="ParentId" 
                                              PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                              Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Where clause should be properly specified in the query inside of the `SelectCommand` attribute in the `asp:SqlDataSource`:
        `SelectCommand="Select  ObjectiveKey, ObjectiveKeyDesc From T_Table ObjectiveKey = @ParentId">`

Try this instead:
        `SelectCommand="Select  ObjectiveKey, ObjectiveKeyDesc From T_Table Where ObjectiveKey = @ParentId`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part, the Where is in the Select already

Comment: and IDs of asp:SqlDataSource and asp:DropDownLists are different in the code snippets (SqlDataSource1 and SqlDataSource2). That is also a typo?

Comment: From the code snippets of the question: asp:SqlDataSource has ID="SqlDataSource2" while all asp:DropDownList reference DataSource="SqlDataSource1"